# CSS circle with two borders of different colors or at least looks like

Tags: css, border, geometry, css-shapes

I have a circle with one border, but I would like to know if there is anyway to achieve a circle with two borders of different colors. I have following CSS producing circle as follows:

```
.circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1.5px solid #fff;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3E78B2;
}

.circle:hover {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3E78B2;
}
```

[Here is link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/premsh/QCVjr/)

You could see currently it has some white border. I would like to add another border on top of white border.

Please let me know if you have any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Nothing pleasant comes to mind. You can add another circle shape (transparent, but with border) and position it directly above or below the existing circle... Or possibly use css border images? Sorry for the not-very-informative suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi u can make this also :

```
.container {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    padding:10px; // ADD THIS ALSO
}
.circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1.5px solid #fff;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3E78B2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #002525; // JUST ADD THIS LINE AND MODIFY YOUR COLOR
}
```

the advantage is that you can also put a blur effect, changing like this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #002525;
```

Comment: that's just awesome! Thank you GilvertOOl

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you're looking to do something along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/QCVjr/1/

```
.circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1.5px solid #000;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.circle:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    content: '';
    background: #3E78B2;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.circle:hover {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}
```

You'll notice that I took your original background color and added it to the `:before` pseudo-element, moved the `#fff` to the background, and made your other border color (in this example, `#000`) the border color of the original element. Both `z-index`es are required to get the right layering.