# create a css badge with multiple borders

Tags: html, css

I need to replicate this in css:

[image]

So far I've got the foundations:

```
<span>&lt; HTML &gt;</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#266c30;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

See my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEmus)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated Code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLGDl

Referencing this post: [CSS circle with two borders of different colors or at least looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560680/css-circle-with-two-borders-of-different-colors-or-at-least-looks-like)

**Working sample:**

```css
.circle_container {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 42px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #266c30;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #266c30; 
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">
<span>HTML</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a border and CSS outline to achieve this:

```
border: 5px solid #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:    0 0 0 5px #266c30;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #266c30;
box-shadow:         0 0 0 5px #266c30;
```

Of course, adjust the border size as needed. You can see this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/NEP8u/.

Comment: you can fall back on outline for ie8 and below since border radius and box shadow won't work so if you want a square with double border for older browser use an ie specific class and add outline

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outline` for this.

Create a white border of `3px` around the green element, and apply a `7px` outline of green color to this.

That would do it. :)

Comment: I'm not sure that would work as the outline does not honour the border-radius?

Comment: Rob Morris is correct, just tried that out - outline does not respect the border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html**

```
<div class="inner container">
    <div class="inner">
        <span>HTML</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.inner{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:green;
    color: white;

    text-align:center;
}
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1%;
}

span{
    line-height:65px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DK5XB/2/)

Of cource you can play with size and font color etc..

Answer (score 0):

I’d simply use an `:after` generated pseudo element for the white inner border, like this:

```
span:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  right:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAGqx

(I changed the span from `display:table-cell` to `block`, because absolute positining in relation to table elements can be tricky in some browsers [especially Firefox], and used `line-height` for vertical centering of the text instead.)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<span>&lt;html&gt;</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
position: centre;
background-color:#266c30;
width:200px;
height:200px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:50%;
color:white;
font-size:60px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing:1px;
border: 5px solid #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:    0 0 0 15px #266c30;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #266c30;
box-shadow:         0 0 0 15px #266c30;
```

}
}